# Emacs: fastest way to achieve this three-window configuration

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

Starting from a fresh configuration of emacs with a single window, what is the fastest way (i.e. the minimum number of keystrokes) to achieve a window layout with three windows (A, B, and C) as follows:

```
+---+---+
|   | B |
| A +---+
|   | C |
+---+---+
```

i.e. a left column displaying one buffer and a right column displaying two buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to store a macro in your .emacs file to make it a one keystroke macro, then using a generic startup:

```
Ctrl-x 3 (divides current window vertically) 
Ctrl-x o (switches from left to right pane)
Ctrl-x 2 (divides right pane into 2)
```

Comment: You might like something like this binding: `(global-set-key (kbd "s-o") 'other-window)` that might be able simplify things.